# Mui AutoComplete, add background to the content of the textfield

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to put background on the text inside the autocomplete TextField.

[image]

But I only achieve this when I select the text using selection pseudo.

here is my code

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  inputRoot: {
    '&::selection': {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
  },
}))
```

I want to put background on text event if its not selected.

Comment: ::first-line works